# Send data to html page through python

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a python-flask app. And my source.py :

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort
import os

from Modules.registry_bend.DockerImageReceiver import http_requester_v2_catalog, read_configurations

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/v1')
def display_index():
    return render_template('index.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # http_requester_v2_catalog("192.168.1.7", 5000)
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=3150)
```

I run this source.py, and then open the browser and hit `localhost:5000/v1`.Then **index.html** appears. So, the challenge is, that a few seconds later I get some data, and I want to add them to index.html. How could it be possible? I have already called **index.html** once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the dynamic data to your HTML by sending context variables through the render template method.

> flask.render_template(template_name_or_list, **context)
>
> Renders a template from the template folder with the given context.
>
> Parameters:
>   template_name_or_list – the name of the template to be rendered, or an iterable with template names the first one existing will be rendered
>
> context – the variables that should be available in the context of the template.

**Example -**

```
return render_template('index.html', variable1=random.random(), variable2=random.random())
```

And in your HTML code you need to include these flask variables.

**Example** -

```
<p> {{variable1}} </p>
<p> {{variable2}} </p>
```

And whenever you refresh you html page in your browser. The new data will be displayed.